# Why does my proftpd server refuse the connection?

Tags: networking, server, ftp, proftpd

I have a small BananaPi (similar to RaspberryPi) running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I would like to use it as an FTP server inside my Network. When trying to connect to the server via port 21 using filezilla on the BananaPi, I am getting the massage

> Status:   Connecting to 127.0.0.1:21...
>
> Status:   Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".

It's the same massage which I get when the server is not even running. In order to set it up I updated and upgraded everything and did the following.

> sudo apt-get install proftpd-basic

and selected *standalone*.

> sudo nano /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf

and changed *IPv6* to "off" and the *ServerName* to "BananaPi".

> sudo nano /etc/proftpd/conf.d/proftp-custom.conf

where I inserted

```
# Ftp user doesn't need a valid shell
<Global>
    RequireValidShell off
</Global>
# Default directory is ftpusers home
    DefaultRoot ~ ftpuser
# Limit login to the ftpuser group
<Limit LOGIN>
    DenyGroup !ftpuser
</Limit>
```

And last I created the user *ftpuser*

> sudo adduser ftpuser --shell /bin/false --home /var/www/upload

and restarted the server via

> sudo service proftpd restart

I uninstalled and reinstalled it several times now without success. What am I doing wrong? How to set it up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open FileZilla
2. Click on **Edit** from the top menu, then click on **Network Configuration Manager**.
   If this is your first time configuring FileZilla's network settings you will be at the **Firewall and route configuration wizard**.
3. Select **Passive** (recommended) and **Allow fallback to other transfer mode on failire** and click **Next**.
4. On the **Configure passive mode** page select **Use the server's external IP address instead** and click **Next**.
5. Select the **Get external IP address from the following URL** option, then you can leave the default of **http://ip.filezilla-project.org/ip.php**
6. Finally on the **Configuration test** page, click on **Test**. If you don't receive any errors than you should be good to go.

Comment: On the test page I am getting the following error: *Response: 150 opening data connection*, *Response: 503 Failure of data connection.*, 
*Server sent unexpected reply.*,
*Connection closed*

Comment: Try to change your FTP mode

Comment: What do you mean by *FTP mode*?

Comment: do you use filezilla

Comment: I'm just using Filezilla for testing purposes on the BananaPi. Of course this scenario is not what I would like to use the FTP server for! The connection fails when using other programms and scripts, as well.